# What are the rules of powers of powers?

Tags: exponentiation

What would $2^{3^4}$ equate to? I can think of two rules that may apply:

$a^{b^c} = a^{(b^c)}$ (Making $2^{3^4} = 2^{81}\approx2.417\cdot10^{24}$)

or
 
$a^{b^c} = (a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ (Making $2^{3^4} = 2^{12} = 4096$)

Which of these is true?

Comment: The first one is true. The power rule is $a ^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation), section "Identities and properties".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Dietrich Burde stated in a comment, the standard convention is that $a^{b^c} = a^{\left(b^c\right)}$. In my mind this convention is due to the fact that $\left(a^b\right)^c$ doesn't need the nested exponent since it is equal to $a^{bc}$ as you observe.